# VBA (excel) copy worksheet to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

right now I am trying to create an excel macro which should copy one worksheet from my workbook. This worksheet should be saved as a new Excel file named with the value from cell B1. 
Everything works fine so far.
The problem is: I want that the copy is a back-up. So the values in the table (copy) should not be connected to the original table.
So to make it short: I just want to copy format+values but not the formulas from the table. 
Do you have any ideas how I can make this work?

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
FPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Artikelnummern"
FName = Worksheets("Test").Cells(1, 2).Value

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       'Possibly overwrite 
without asking
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName & ".xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line:

```
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
```

With:

```
shtToExport.Cells.Copy
wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count - 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count - 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: @lucas  have you tried the code in my answer here ? is it working for you as you wanted ?

Comment: Runtimeerror 9; it says that the index is out of range (hope thats the right translation)

Comment: Thank you so far for your help, had not enough time yesterday, sorry. So It marks the whole sheet, creates a new workbook but does not copy the data into the new one. As mentioned above: Error occures

Comment: @lucas to which `Worksheet` you want to paste it to ? the last one ?

Comment: the macro should create a new workbook. So this workbook is empty (default Sheet1 is in it). It would be great if the macro would copy it to this first sheet. Otherwise, it can also create a new sheet.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this: Before I close the workbook (new one) with this line: wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
Can I insert there something like .Value = .Value.
I am new to VBA so I am not sure how to use the code for the new workbook. The problem is that I can not write a macro in the new workbook because I always create new ones. Is there any command so that I have access to the new workbook and change these formulas with the code above?